# How to call environment file from Perl mmodule

Tags: perl, unix

I have a Perl script test.Perl which is taking all values for my $variable (Import) from environment file. Perl script will take values only if your environment file is .pm (environment.pm).

Now when I trying to import $variables value from environment.env (not .pm) file then perl script is not loading variable values.

Is there any way we can use environment file with some other extension apart from .pm and refer in perl script.

Comment: What do you mean by "environment file"? Please include a demonstration of the problem in your question!

Comment: Please explain carefully what you mean by *"taking all values for my $variable (Import) from environment file"*. Do you mean "my" as in the Perl language word `my`? What do you mean by `(Import)`? What is an "environment file"?

Comment: how to source a shell script [environment variables] in perl script without forking a subshell? I hope it will help.                                                                  
I want to call "env.sh " from "my_perl.pl" without forking a subshell. I tried with backtics and system like this --> system (. env.sh) [dot space env.sh] , however wont work. Please help me out.

Comment: When you use backticks or `system` you **do** fork a subshell. It will set the env. vars in that shell and then exit so the vars vanish together with the subshell. [Edit] your question and show the env. file and the Perl code that ought to benefit from these env. variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Perl Function do

```
do 'filename.env'
```

might do depending on your needs. (sourcing perl Code)

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html for further information.

if you want to get the changes to the env by your shell script, you have to copy them

```
my $env_serialized=qx(myscript.sh | env);
my %new_env= (map {/^(.*?)=(.*)/} split("\n",$env_serialized)});
foreach my $key (keys %new_env) {
     $ENV{$key} = $new_env{$key};
}
```

HTH
Georg

Comment: I had to change it onto: my $env_serialized=qx(source myscript.sh && env);